# How to deploy plain-html site on GitLab Pages

Tags: deployment, gitlab

I had plain HTML site where the files, built by `gulp`, were in `/docs` folder.

I found this repo https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html in official pages and tried it, changing `/public` directory in `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `/docs` directory, and had error: `CI` always showed me `failed` error on build.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - docs
  only:
  - master
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Then why you asked about it?

Comment: @InziKhan Because I was searching for answer for a long time and there is nothing I can find, so I posted answer here for other people to find on stackoverflow

Comment: That's good then.

Comment: Now you've changed the question such that your answer *doesn't actually answer it*. You've included the answer as part of the question and asked a different one. Also don't put meta content in questions.

Comment: Finally *"It didn't work well."* is a pretty terrible problem description. **What actually happened?**

Answer (score 2):

The `public` folder is REQUIRED. You can't put your files in other folder no matter what.

Comment: Given that this is all shown in the examples https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html, why do you think it needs cross-posting to SO? Was there some specific *problem* you had to solve that you could write as a proper question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe In that project there is a big problem: He haven't said that `public` folder is REQUIRED. And that's made me sitting for a long time trying to find what's wrong with my project.

Comment: It absolutely **does** say that: *"The above example expects to put all your HTML files in the `public/` directory."* Also `artifacts: paths: - public` would be a bit of a giveaway, no? But you could still write a better question based on that - what happened when you *didn't* put it in `public/`? What observed behaviour would lead someone to make a search that could possibly find them this question? Self-answered questions must still meet the SO quality requirements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've changed my answer to make link to original answer

Comment: @jonrsharpe `The above example expects...` - not mean it's REQUIRED. I will change my post now.

Comment: As well as the question being useless, this answer is not accurate - this isn't *"no matter what"*, or *"REQUIRED"*, it's just a documented assumption in the default setup. You could also change the configuration to the directory (or directories, probably) you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Have you tested it? Try and you will see, that it is not working with other directories, I've tested it, and that's why I'm writing this post.

Comment: You're right, but that *is* documented: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#explore-the-contents-of-gitlab-ci-yml

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's so tiny sentence in nearly hidden place, that's the problem of this document. I didn't spent for an 4 hours searching the error, if I knew that `public` it's just required. And thats all. And I thought as you are: "The above example expects to put all your HTML files in the public/ directory." - that's said that I can change the folder, because there was no rule. But there is rule and it's terrible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do I do now? The question and answer are in big minus... If somebody have this problem and they will seу my post it will confuse them, they can think that my answer is wrong and `public` folder is not required...

Comment: Now you hope that, having improved things, some people find it useful and vote it up.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Maybe it's better to delete it and write new one? I'm new to posting on stackoverflow, so I don't know if there could be penalties for that

Comment: No, it isn't. Deleted posts with downvotes still count towards automated bans. You are better leaving it and hoping to gain some upvotes to balance it out. And hopefully next time *starting* with a clear Q&A!

Answer (score 2):

2017:

> The public folder is REQUIRED.

Not anymore.

See [GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#configure-the-static-file-directory-in-gitlab-pages) (June 2023)

> ### Configure the static file directory in GitLab Pages
>
> You can now configure the static file directory for GitLab Pages to any name (by default `public`).
> This makes it easier to use Pages with popular static site frameworks such as Next.js, Astro, or Eleventy, without needing to change the output folder in their configuration.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_1/pages-configure-publish-folder.png -- Configure the static file directory in GitLab Pages]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/introduction.html#customize-the-default-folder) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10126).