# GltLab Pages 401 - You don't have permission to access the resource

Tags: gitlab, cloudflare, gitlab-pages

Classic GitLab Pages setup issue. Seems I face this every time I try to host a page on GitLab Pages.

[image: GltLab Pages 401 - You don't have permission to access the resource.]

This time though I forgot how to get past it. All settings look correct:

[image: CloudFlare DNS Settings]

I've turned off all HTTPS/TLS/SSL on the domain in Cloudflare just to give it an easier time connecting.

GitLab Pages setting is stuck on forcing HTTPS. No idea how this gets stuck like this?

[image: GitLab Pages forcing HTTPS]

More settings:
[image: GitLab Page 401 settings]

[image]
[image]

Any insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Maybe DNS changes are still propagating? ‍♂️

Comment: What is your 'page access contrôle setting set to?

Comment: @YassinHajaj, yes Visibility Settings are public all around.

Comment: I think it's the LetsEncrypt cert: "Something went wrong while obtaining the Let's Encrypt certificate.". Got that after two retries. Trying again...

Answer (score 1):

Missing `gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Also, a `public/` folder not the root is required.
See [How to deploy plain-html site on GitLab Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967725/how-to-deploy-plain-html-site-on-gitlab-pages)

Try adding `gitlab-ci.yml` and `public/` or create from repo from a GitLab Template:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pages/getting_started/pages_new_project_template.html

Like this one:
https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html

Answer (score 0):

If the `gitlab-ci.yml` is ok this happen because a bug (at least in my self hosted).

If you launch the custom domain creation before to create the CNAME DNS records then it fails the first time and then is not capable to do the Let's Encrypt validation.

Note: In my setup is not required to validate the domain, only the CNAME records.